# Integration between Two IdentityServer4 (aspnet identity)

Tags: asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, identityserver4, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to do IdentityServer4(**A**) integration with another IdentityServer4(**B**) implementation. These two are currently working independently from each other.

I already did some progress with this, but I'm feeling that I'm not doing it in the correct way.
**IdentityServer(A)**

- Added a new client (AllowedGrantTypes = **GrantTypes.Implicit,**)

**IdentityServer(B)**

- added new authentication source **AddOpenIdConnect**

```html
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "Identity Server A", options =>
{
  options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
  options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
  options.SaveTokens = true;
  options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

  options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
  options.ClientId = "identityServerB";

  options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
  options.Scope.Add("roles");

  options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
  {
    ctx.Principal.Claims.Append(new Claim("LoginSource", "IdentityServerA"));

  };
});
```

The current result is, after the use of the external login mechanism on **B**

- the account is being created as expected on **B,**
- the user is logged off on **A**
- **B** the aspneUser table is not populated with user's data from **A**
- **B** populating the user claims table with users data.

At this stage, I need a way or a best practice to implement this:

1. Create the account from A to B, and B to A, in the case doesn't exist.
2. Merge the created account from the source, or just a way to link ids
3. Be able to access to the Identity server clients no matter the authentication source.
4. Associate a role or any claim to identify the Login Source.
5. update user information and reset password

Comment: The integration between two identity providers like in your case can be done by using external idps, much like you can use google or facebook as an external idp for any regular identity server implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is called Federation Gateway.

What is federation gateway and why is it needed?
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/federation_gateway.html

How to implement federation gateway?
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html

Comment: Thank you! Yesterday I was able to config the **B** to create the account and the claims in the correct way. There is "ExternalController" on quickstart that you can manage and develop your custom workflow on the callback. But I'm still a problem with users logged out on **A**, and I can't auto login with the created account on **B**. There is some gap with no documentation on how to implement this. Only the Note [link]http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html helped a little bit... :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed with the Federation Gateway documentation
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html

Used the 4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal quickstart to identify and fix the issue.

[External Authentication QuickStart](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Quickstarts/4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal)